# Parsing YAML file using yaml-cpp error

Tags: c++, yaml, ros, yaml-cpp

I am trying to parse info from a .yaml file with camera calibration into a "sensor_msgs::CameraInfo" message in ROS.

I manage to parse both INTs and strings, but are having issues when I get to the double vector/matrix.

Here is my code:

```
sensor_msgs::CameraInfo yamlToCameraInfo(std::string leftOrRightCam)
{
  YAML::Node camera_info_yaml = YAML::LoadFile(leftOrRightCam + ".yaml");
  sensor_msgs::CameraInfo camera_info_msg;
  camera_info_msg.width = camera_info_yaml["image_width"].as<uint32_t>();
  camera_info_msg.height = camera_info_yaml["image_height"].as<uint32_t>();
  camera_info_msg.distortion_model = camera_info_yaml["distortion_model"].as<std::string>();
  camera_info_msg.D = camera_info_yaml["distortion_coefficients"].as<double>();
  camera_info_msg.K = camera_info_yaml["camera_matrix"].as<double>();

  return camera_info_msg;

}
```

The error I get is this:

> error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are
>   'sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_ >::_D_type {aka
>   std::vector >}' and 'double')
>   camera_info_msg.D =
>   camera_info_yaml["distortion_coefficients"].as();

The documentation for the cameraInfo message is located here: http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html

Tutorial for the yaml-cpp package: https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial

The "Distortion coefficients" part of my yaml file lokk like this:

> distortion_coefficients:
>    rows: 1
>    cols: 5
>    data: [-0.167477, 0.023595, 0.004069, -0.002996, 0.000000]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Here the `distortion_coefficients` node is a map. I guess you need to iterate through the `distortion_coefficients` node and get the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error on this line:

```
camera_info_msg.D = camera_info_yaml["distortion_coefficients"].as<double>();
```

suggests that the left-hand-side is an `std::vector<double>` whereas the right-hand-side is a `double`. Instead:

```
camera_info_msg.D = camera_info_yaml["distortion_coefficients"].as<std::vector<double>>();
```

Comment: Yes. the issues was indeed that D is a vector. I didn't get your specific codeline to work, but I had it already working using this bit "    for (std::size_t i=0;i<camera_info_yaml["distortion_coefficients"]["data"].size();i++) {
      camera_info_msg.D.push_back(camera_info_yaml["distortion_coefficients"]["data"][i].as<double>());
    }"